# Calculating distance between two points with QGIS 2.14.0

Tags: qgis, point, distance

I have two shapefiles with the following information:

- List A:
  `ID 1 | xA | yA | ID 2`
- List B:
  `ID 1 | xB | yB | ID 2`

`{x;y} = {lat;lon}`

I want to calculate the distance between two points, e.g. ID 1: distance from `{xA,yA}` to `{xB,yB}`.

The KBS is WGS 84 and I need the result in meters. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: If I join the two tables to one, then I have an attribute table with an starting point and an end point (x and y coordinates for  each). Would it somehow be possible to calculate the difference (m) between the start and the end point with the field calculator?

Answer (score 3):

First merge your two shapefiles into one (copy/paste all your points from one to the other, or use the tool **Merge Shapefiles to one...** in *Vector > Data Management Tools*). Check that all your points have their ID in one unique field.

Next go to *Processing > Toolbox*. In the toolbox windows, search **Convert points to line(s)** and open it.
Select your shape in the **Points** field, and select your ID in **Order by...** and **Separate by...**, give a name to your new layer and click **Run**.

Now, all your points that have the same ID should be joined together by a line. You can now generate the length of all lines with the **Field Calculator**.

If lengths seems to be false, convert your line shape from WGS84 to an other CRS that use the meter for unit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Distance matrix

> Vector > Analysis Tools > Distance Matrix

[QGIS Documentation: Distance matrix](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_analysis_tools/distancematrix.html)

Comment: I tried to use the distance matrix function, but I’m not able to select the ID field. Is there a setting I have to make before running it or why is this? It should be possible to select that, shouldn’t it?